# Axios Typescript on Next.js headers type issue

Tags: typescript, axios, next.js, http-headers

I configured a next.js app with JWT authentication that comes from a Spring Boot API(Next is used as a client). All the next.js was done inspired on this tutorial:
https://www.mikealche.com/software-development/how-to-implement-authentication-in-next-js-without-third-party-libraries

Axios: 0.24.0
Next: 12.0.7
React: 17.0.2
SWR: 1.1.0

On a page like [id].tsx I use axios to make a request

```
const headers = api.defaults.headers;
const fetcher = (url:string)=> axios.get(url,{headers}).then(res => res.data)

const router = useRouter()
    const { id } = router.query
    const path = process.env.API_URL + "events/" + id;
    const { data } = useSWR<EventType>(path, fetcher);

... rest of the component uses "data"...and after the component...

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [
      '/events/[...id]',
    ],
    fallback: true,
  }
}

export default EventPage;
```

on "headers" I got a typescript error:

```
(property) AxiosRequestConfig<any>.headers?: AxiosRequestHeaders
Type 'HeadersDefaults' is not assignable to type 'AxiosRequestHeaders'.
  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'HeadersDefaults'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(68, 3): The expected type comes from property 'headers' which is declared here on type 'AxiosRequestConfig<any>'
```

there is a api.ts file that created the axios object I use on the whole app for all requests

```
import Axios from "axios";

const api = Axios.create({
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
});

export default api;
```

That api is imported on [id].tsx

And the Auth context is created on auth.tsx

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import LoadingPage from '../pages/loading';
import api from '../services/api';

const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        async function loadUserFromStorage() {
            const token = window.localStorage.getItem('jwtAuthToken')
            if (token) {
                api.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`
            }
            setLoading(false)
        }
        loadUserFromStorage()
    }, [])

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ loading }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}


export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext)

export const ProtectRoute = ({ children }) => {
    const auth = useAuth();
    const router = useRouter();
    if (
        (auth.loading && router.pathname !== '/') ||
        (router.pathname !== '/' && !window.localStorage.getItem('jwtAuthToken'))
    ) {
      return <LoadingPage />; 
    }
    return children;
  };
```

auth.loading also has type error, that I don't know how to solve yet.

All of that is applied to the _app.js:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <ProtectRoute>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ProtectRoute>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

All works fine on dev mode, but I can't build due to the type errors.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to solve it looking into index.d.ts from axios on node_modules. On every get(every page) and delete(every material-ui card with a delete icon) request I was doing, post and put didn't need because on passing the headers as props to forms the type changed.

```
const headers = api.defaults.headers.get;
```

It's necessary to add the method to make the type compatible.
And for auth.loading, on auth.tsx

```
const AuthContext = createContext<{loading: boolean}>({loading: false});
```